# AC and Krull's theorem equivalence

Tags: set-theory

It is well known that the axiom of choice can be used to prove Krull's theorem which states that every ring has a maximal ideal. However, i heard once that Krull's theorem is equivalent to the AC (or to Zorn's lemma). Is that true?
So, we suggest each ring (perhaps, each commutative ring) has a maximal ideal and now we need to build some ring to prove the AC (Zorn's lemma, Zermelo theorem etc). Could anybody explain how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried searching the site before asking?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27163/nilradicals-without-zorns-lemma/27165#27165 (Also a google search for "axiom of choice"+krull returns that link in the third place, and the paper by Hodges from that answer as the second result).

Comment: Yes, i have, but a bit sluggishly. Thank you!

Comment: Nikita, welcome to MathOverflow. Asaf, since the question to which you link to is not the same as this question, why not just answer this question with a link to Hodge's paper? Indeed, I was say that that answer over there is more an answer to this question here than that one (although of course they are closely related).

Comment: To be honest, after i had asked my question, i found the Hodge's paper at the Journal of London mathematical society, but couldn't subscribe for the Journal (there was something like 'such page doesn't exists'). Also i hope it's not necessary to pay for it. If it's not a problem, can anybody give the link to the Hodge's paper or send it me to the email?

Answer (score 6):

Originally the proof was given by Hodges, from 1979 [1].

Banaschewski gave a new proof of the theorem in 1994 [2].

---

**Bibliography:**

1. Hodges, W., [**Krull implies Zorn**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-19.2.285). *Journal of the London Mathematical Society* **2** (1979), 285-287.
2. Banaschewski, B., [**A New Proof that “Krull implies Zorn”**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19940400405). *Mathematical Logic Quarterly* **40** (1994), 478-480.